# Android Component for Voting

Tags: android, components, voting

I am developing an Android App (SDK 5.0) and I need an component for voting, like StackOverflow, with up and down icons. Is there an Android component for doing that? How can I do this in Android?

Thanks,
Guilherme Matos

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a source generating place. You should show some effort, not just ask for ready-made solution.

Comment: I am developing my own componentes. I just want to know if someone has done the same thing.

Comment: I guess yes - even in official SO app you can find it.